How to do groupby on multi index dataframe based on condition
I have a multi index dataframe, and I want to combine rows based on certain conditions and I want to combine rows per index.
import pandas as pd

#  data
data = {
    'date': ['01/01/17', '02/01/17', '03/01/17', '01/01/17', '02/01/17', '03/01/17'],
    'language': ['python', 'python', 'python', 'r', 'r', 'r'],
    'ex_complete': [6, 5, 10, 8, 8, 8]
}

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert DataFrame to JSON
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')

# Convert JSON data back to DataFrame
df_from_json = pd.read_json(json_data, orient='records')

# Set date and language as multi-index
df_from_json.set_index(['date', 'language'], inplace=True)

df_from_json.sort_index(inplace= True)

df_from_json

1st Problem:
I want to combine the dates '01/01/17', '02/01/17' and rename as '1_2', this should give me 4 rows:
2 rows for '1_2' - (Python and R) and 2 rows for '03/01/17' (Python and R)
2nd Problem:
I want to combine Python and R rows and rename as Python_R, this should give 3 rows for 3 dates.
Any guidance or pointer will be hugely appreciated.

I don't see why you cobvert the df to JSON then back to df, all that achives is comverting the 'date' field from dtype='object'(/string) to 'datetime64', which you can do more directly.

IIUC use DataFrame.rename with aggregate, e.g. sum:
out = (df_from_json.rename({pd.Timestamp('01/01/17'):'1_2',
                            pd.Timestamp('02/01/17'):'1_2'}, level=0)
                   .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())
print (out)
                              ex_complete
date                language             
2017-03-01 00:00:00 python             10
                    r                   8
1_2                 python             11
                    r                  16


out = (df_from_json.rename({'python':'Python_R', 'r':'Python_R'}, level=1)
                    .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())
print (out)
                     ex_complete
date       language             
2017-01-01 Python_R           14
2017-02-01 Python_R           13
2017-03-01 Python_R           18


could you also please let me know what can I do if I want to retain original rows as well along with aggregated rows ?

@Ezio - Do you think solution without .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum() ?

I think I got what i wanted. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ff60uP30s7WXdDSxFqDDzxMh2olstlW9?usp=sharing
